# valgrind: readdwarf.c assertion failed when linking with ArmPL and Pthread

Tags: c++, linux, arm, valgrind, nvidia-jetson

I'm trying to use valgrind to debug a program for Nvidia Jetson, but I keep getting an assertion failed at startup. This seems to occur only when I link the program with both the ArmPL (Arm Performance Libraries) and Pthread libraries.

This is a minimal sample to reproduce the issue:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
   std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```

To compile:

```
g++ -g -O0 main.cpp -L/mnt/data/opt/lib -larmpl -lpthread
```

To run:

```
valgrind ./a.out
```

Output:

```
==8903== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8903== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8903== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8903== Command: ./a.out
==8903== 
--8903-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x11
--8903-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x11
--8903-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x11
--8903-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x11
--8903-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x11
--8903-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x11
--8903-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x11
--8903-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x11
--8903-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x11
--8903-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x11
--8903-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x11
--8903-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x11
--8903-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x11
--8903-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x11
--8903-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x11
--8903-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x11
--8903-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x11

valgrind: m_debuginfo/readdwarf.c:2396 (copy_convert_CfiExpr_tree): Assertion 'srcix >= 0 && srcix < VG_(sizeXA)(srcxa)' failed.

host stacktrace:
==8903==    at 0x5803DBA0: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-arm64-linux)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 8903)
==8903==    at 0x4016D44: mmap (mmap64.c:59)
==8903==    by 0x4005627: _dl_map_segments (dl-map-segments.h:94)
==8903==    by 0x4005627: _dl_map_object_from_fd (dl-load.c:1181)
==8903==    by 0x4007C5F: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2460)
==8903==    by 0x400BCE7: openaux (dl-deps.c:63)
==8903==    by 0x4015A53: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:196)
==8903==    by 0x400C057: _dl_map_object_deps (dl-deps.c:249)
==8903==    by 0x40037EF: dl_main (rtld.c:1726)
==8903==    by 0x4014D6F: _dl_sysdep_start (dl-sysdep.c:253)
==8903==    by 0x40018C3: _dl_start_final (rtld.c:414)
==8903==    by 0x4001B47: _dl_start (rtld.c:523)
==8903==    by 0x40011C7: ??? (in /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so)


Note: see also the FAQ in the source distribution.
It contains workarounds to several common problems.
In particular, if Valgrind aborted or crashed after
identifying problems in your program, there's a good chance
that fixing those problems will prevent Valgrind aborting or
crashing, especially if it happened in m_mallocfree.c.

If that doesn't help, please report this bug to: www.valgrind.org

In the bug report, send all the above text, the valgrind
version, and what OS and version you are using.  Thanks.
```

The error doesn't appear if linking only with ArmPL or pthread.

System used:

```
Nvidia Jetson AGX Xavier
Ubuntu 18.04
gcc version 7.5.0
valgrind version 3.13.0
ArmPL version 21.1_Ubuntu-18.04_gcc-7.5
```

Comment: Please try a recent Valgrind. If that does not work, open a defect request on https://bugs.kde.org/

Comment: @PaulFloyd I just tried with version 3.20.0 compiled from source and got the same result. I'll open a defect request.